# JavaFX and Controller, how to change scene based on the message from the server?

Tags: multithreading, javafx, server, client, fxml

I have created a quizapp which is a multi client server application(TCP). The server sends messages to the client and based on the message the client follows certain instructions. This works perfectly well with Swing. However I want to implement the application to JavaFX using Scene Builder.

I've created different fxml files so that I can have different scenes.
I've created a method(`loadUI(String fxmlFile))` in the Controller class that allows me to swap the scene with a push of button. I've tested it and it works.

When we are sending messages from the server to the client(in Controller) the message loops and the scenes don't swap.

Could it be that the controller class instantiates in a way whenever i call loadUI?

Here is my Controller Class:

```
public class Controller implements Runnable {

Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 56565); // 172.20.201.169
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
Thread thread = new Thread(this);

@FXML
private Button altButton1 = new Button();
@FXML
private Button altButton2 = new Button();
@FXML
private Button altButton3 = new Button();
@FXML
private Button altButton4 = new Button();

@FXML
private Button continueButton = new Button();

List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

public Controller() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Constructor");
    thread.start();
}


public void listOfButtons() {
    buttons.add(altButton1);
    buttons.add(altButton2);
    buttons.add(altButton3);
    buttons.add(altButton4);
}

public void handleAnswers(ActionEvent event) {
    listOfButtons();
    Button temp = (Button) event.getSource();

    if (event.getSource().equals("Peter")) {
        temp.getStyleClass().add("button_right");
    } else {
        temp.getStyleClass().add("button_wrong");
        for (Button button : buttons) {
            if (button.getText().equals("Peter")) {
                button.getStyleClass().add("button_right");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (Button button : buttons) {
        button.setDisable(true);
        button.setOpacity(1);
    }
    continueButton.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println(temp.getText());
}

/**
 * Method swaps Scene
 *
 * @param fxmlFile
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void loadUI(String fxmlFile) throws IOException {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
    Scene tempScene = new Scene(root);

    ObservableList<Window> windows = Stage.getWindows();

    for (Window window : windows) {
        System.out.println(window);
    }

    Stage window = (Stage) windows.get(0);
    window.setScene(tempScene);
    window.show();
}

public void continueToNextQuestion() {

    continueButton.setVisible(false);

    for (Button button : buttons) {
        button.setDisable(false);
        button.getStyleClass().remove("button_wrong");
        button.getStyleClass().remove("button_right");
    }
}

public void continueFromWait() {
    try {
        loadUI("question.fxml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showTheMessageFromServer(String message) throws IOException {
    if (message.startsWith("Welcome")) {
        message = message.substring(message.indexOf(' '));
        if (message.contains("1")) {
            loadUI("category.fxml");
        } else {
            loadUI("wait.fxml");
        }
    } else {
        loadUI("question.fxml");
    }
}//showTheMessageFromTheServer

@Override
public void run() {
    Object obj;

    try {
        while ((obj = in.readObject()) != null) {
            if (obj instanceof Question) {
                Question question = (Question) obj;
                //   showTheQuestion(question);

            } else if (obj instanceof String) {
                String message = (String) obj;
                System.out.println(message);
                showTheMessageFromServer(message);

            } else if (obj instanceof Integer[]) {
                Integer[] points = (Integer[]) obj;
                // showThePoints(points);
            }
        }//while

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Here is my Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("question.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("QuizApp");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 500));
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

OUTPUT:
Constructor
Welcome: Player 1
Constructor
Welcome: Player 2
Constructor
Welcome: Player 1
Constructor
Welcome: Player 2
Constructor
Welcome: Player 1

Comment: you _must not_ change the active scenegraph (nor any properties of any nodes inside) off the fx application thread! To fix, wrap f.i. loadUi into Platform.runlater(...).

Comment: Also it'a bad idea to mix ui code and communication layer that closely. Limit the controller to receiving getting passed the messages and move everything else to a seperate class. Also don't initialize `@FXML` annotated fields. Those are supposed to be assigned by `FXMLLoader` some time after it creates the controller instance. IF you want to start some background operation updating the gui, start this from the `initialize` method.

Comment: However load the scene again every time `showMessageFromServer` is called with something but `"Welcome"` as parameter. Every time you load the scene a new controller instance is created. You indeed spawn more and more of those threads...